# wpf hide menu in fullscreen

Tags: wpf, menu, hide, fullscreen

I need to hide main menu? when i switched in fullscreen mode. How to make it?
I heve menu like this:

```
   <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <DockPanel></DockPanel>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </Menu.ItemsPanel>
                    <MenuItem Header="Файл">
                        <MenuItem Header="Выход" Click="biExit_Click" />
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="Данные">
                        <MenuItem Header="Импорт" Click="biImportData_ItemClick" />
                        <MenuItem Header="Перестроить кэш" Click="biRebuidCache_ItemClick" />
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="Режим" x:Name="ModeSelector">
                        <MenuItem Header="Договора" Click="Mode1_Click" />
                        <MenuItem Header="Имущество" Click="Mode2_Click" />
                    </MenuItem>
                </Menu>
```

And I have swithcher on key press F11:

```
  if (e.Key == Key.F11)
                {
                    if(_fullScreenWindow == null)
                      {
                        MinHeight = MinHeightDefault;
                        MinWidth = MinWidthDefault;
                        MaxHeight = MaxHeightDefault;
                        MaxWidth = MaxWidthDefault;

                        _fullScreenWindow = true;
                        WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
                        WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
                        ResizeMode = ResizeMode.CanResize;
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                        WindowStyle = WindowStyle.ToolWindow;
                        ResizeMode = ResizeMode.CanResize;
                        _fullScreenWindow = null;
                      }
                }
```

I apologize in advance if this is a stupid question, but I caanot figure out how to make it in a proper way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your menu a Name:

```
<Menu x:Name="MyMenu" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <Menu.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <DockPanel></DockPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Menu.ItemsPanel>
                <MenuItem Header="Файл">
                    <MenuItem Header="Выход" Click="biExit_Click" />
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Данные">
                    <MenuItem Header="Импорт" Click="biImportData_ItemClick" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Перестроить кэш" Click="biRebuidCache_ItemClick" />
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Режим" x:Name="ModeSelector">
                    <MenuItem Header="Договора" Click="Mode1_Click" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Имущество" Click="Mode2_Click" />
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
```

And hide it when fullscreen:

```
 if (e.Key == Key.F11)
            {
                if(_fullScreenWindow == null)
                  {
                    MinHeight = MinHeightDefault;
                    MinWidth = MinWidthDefault;
                    MaxHeight = MaxHeightDefault;
                    MaxWidth = MaxWidthDefault;

                    _fullScreenWindow = true;
                    WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
                    WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
                    ResizeMode = ResizeMode.CanResize;
                    MyMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; //HERE
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                    WindowStyle = WindowStyle.ToolWindow;
                    ResizeMode = ResizeMode.CanResize;
                    _fullScreenWindow = null;
                    MyMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //HERE
                  }
            }
```